# robust computation of Groebner basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve numerically polynomial systems of equations, over the reals. I am coming across the following phenomenon: let's say that i have a system of 7 equations with 7 unknowns. I am using the function GroebnerBasis in Mathematica to compute a Groebner basis. Now, the feasibility or the infeasibility of the system might vary, depending on the monomial order that i chose, e.g. if i change the monomial order, GroebnerBasis might return that the ideal generated by my equations is the entire polynomial ring, which was not the case with the previous order. This leads me to ask: what is the most reliable algorithm or software for computing Groebner basis?

Comment: I hear Magma is pretty good at these things.

Comment: @RagibZaman: Thanks, i had not heard about Magma before, looks very nice.

Comment: Maple is very good but it is a commercial package. If you use it, I suggest selecting Faugère's F4 algorithm.